# Maximum number of ignored tags

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags

I have added the tag "r" to the list of ignored tag 3 times but I continue to see question tagged with "r".

Is there perhaps a maximum number of ignored tags and I have reached?

Comment: How many PokéMon do you have now?

Comment: 169 if I am not wrong

Comment: I am trying to add more tags to the ignored list and they get added correctly anyway... the problem is only with the "r"

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, and wondering how many tags I could add before I started running into any performance problems.